# Powershell query WIN->LINUX

Tags: linux, windows, powershell, share, wmi

This is my first post in StackOverflow. Here goes my question:

Two servers:

Linux-FileServer, having different shares, open port 445 (NO ACCESS VIA SSH)

Windows-I can access the linux server from a mmc console, view all shares, share permissions, ntfs permissions.

What I want to do is to get all share permissions (not ntfs) from each share allocated in the linux machine.

I want to do that using powershell, I've seen solutions by usign WMI but I can't query linux using WMI.

Does anyone knows how I could do that using Powershell? MMC console on windows can access that information so I think that what I want to do is possible.

Thank you!

Comment: If thats a normal File Server, then whats wrong in invoking a FTP. If samba, then you can try `smbstatus --shares`

Comment: Please read about this: [Ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you, sorry I have no access to that linux machine via ssh or terminal.

Comment: OK. Let me ask you straight forward. if thats an FTP share then you can directly access that I believe. If not then what kind of share it is  and how are manually accessing now.

Comment: I can access all shares via UNC \\linuxmachine\sharexxx with r/w permissions. From MMC (Microsoft management console) I can add Shared Folders Snap-In and then Connect to other computer (linuxmachine) and I can see all shares, on properties watch all share/ntfs permissions. There are thousands of shares so thats why I have to script it. I already have ntfs permissions for all shares, I need those on share level.

Comment: `New-PSDrive -Name P -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\server\share`

Answer (score 1):

Mount a network path as a temporary drive and then being able to browse it using the shell.

Use this command to mount the network path \server\share to P:

```
New-PSDrive -Name P -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\server\share
```

YOu can use ***net use*** or Wscript.Network for it:

```
$net = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network
$net.MapNetworkDrive("u:", "\\server\share", $false, "domain\user", "password")
```

Note: I am not sure how you are entering to that server without ssh or something. If you have the access via UNC then you can simply map it or use it like I have mentioned. Else please use **Posh-SSH** module(if you have ssh access) which will help you to access.